# need to generate a random number, but every digit in that number can't be higher than 6 (in C)

Tags: c, random

I need to generate a random number that has 4 digits, but I have to make sure that every digit is not higher than 6, Is it possible? if so, how can I do that? :)
(In C)

Comment: Try `rand()` % 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest option would be to generate 4 different random numbers in the range of 0 to 6, then add them up, but multiply the first one by 1, second one by 10 etc.

```
int a = rand() % 7;
int b = rand() % 7;
int c = rand() % 7;
int d = rand() % 7;

int e = a + 10 * b + 100 * c + 1000 * d;
```

Comment: oh ok, thank you very much!

Comment: You might want a non-zero value for `d`; use `d = 1 + rand() % 6;` to generate a random value 1..6.

Comment: Depends on OP's usecase, but non-zero first digit may indeed be desirable i guess